# How to work out $\left.\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right\rvert_{h(x,y)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, change-of-variable

If $f=g(x,y)$, and $h=i(x,y)$, how to work out
$$\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right\rvert_h
$$
in terms of partial derivatives like $\left.\frac{\partial ...}{\partial ...}\right\rvert_x$ and $\left.\frac{\partial ...}{\partial ...}\right\rvert_y$?
I would say $f=g(x,y)=j(x,y,h)$, but it ends up with a correlation for $\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right\rvert_{h,y}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wish to take the partial derivative of $g(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ when $i(x,y)$ is the independent variable.

You would *need to be able* to set $f=j(x,h)$ for some  function $j$ such that $\large g(x,y)=j(x,i(x,y))$.

$$\left.\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right\vert_h = j^{[1,0]}(x,i(x,y))$$

Where $j^{[1,0]}$ s the partial deriative of bivalent function $j$ with respect to its first argument.

---

Now, *finding* such a function might be tricky.  But it is essentially what we do in a change of variables, when $u=x, v=i(x,y)$.